debian 12 can not change core file size
I have this in my /etc/security/limits.conf:
*                soft    core            unlimited
*                hard    core            unlimited

And no other files in /etc/security/limits.d.
Added session required pam_limits.so in /etc/pam.d/common-session and /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive.
After re-login and reboot, the output of ulimit -c is always 0.
But ulimit -c 100000 or ulimit -c unlimited works.（I don't want to use this ad hoc approach.）

Can't really check this, but Debian 12 is probably systemd, so you should edit the file /etc/systemd/system.conf and change DefaultLimitCORE.

@Gerrit I tried it, but ulimit -c output is still 0.

I think what you are running into, is that the asterisk wildcard does not work for the root user. Also, forget the system.conf, I thought at first that you ran into a hard limit, but that is not the case. Including pam_limits, is not necessary, because pam_systemd will take the limits.conf values also.

@Gerrit I changed * to root in /etc/security/limits.conf. And it works.  But why * doesn't work?

Nice. :-) Yes, well the wildcard sort of has the meaning everyone except root. This is generally useful, because you don't want to apply hard limits to root by accident.

Maybe some of these additional steps and considerations that could help resolve the issue with core dump limits which are not being applied correctly:
a. Checking PAM Configuration in /etc/pam.d/:

To ensure that the pam_limits.so module is included in all relevant PAM configuration files, not just /etc/pam.d/common-session and /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive. You might also want to include it in /etc/pam.d/login if it's not already there:
session required pam_limits.so


If you use sudo to switch to root, ensure the limits are applied by adding pam_limits.so to /etc/pam.d/sudo as well.

b. Verification of Limits Using pam_limits:

Creating a new non-root user and to test if the limits work for that user. This helps to verify if the issue is specific to the root user configuration.

c. Systemd User Services:

If you're using systemd user services, ensure the limits are set correctly. You can check and set limits in the user-specific systemd configuration file:
~/.config/systemd/user.conf


Ensure that DefaultLimitCORE is set to infinity:
[Manager]
DefaultLimitCORE=infinity



d. Checking the /etc/security/limits.d/:

Although you mentioned there are no files in /etc/security/limits.d/, it’s good practice to double-check. Ensure no files are unintentionally added that might override or conflict with your settings.

e. Apply System-Wide Changes:

Sometimes changes require a full system reboot to take effect properly. If you haven’t done so already, try rebooting the system.

f. Use sysctl for System-Wide Core Dump Settings:

For additional control over core dumps, you can set system-wide kernel parameters using sysctl:
sudo sysctl -w fs.suid_dumpable=2
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core.%e.%p.%h.%t


Make these changes persistent by adding them to /etc/sysctl.conf:
fs.suid_dumpable = 2
kernel.core_pattern = /tmp/core.%e.%p.%h.%t



g. Verify Effective Limits:

After re-login or reboot, verify the effective limits applied by PAM and systemd. You can do this by inspecting the limits with the prlimit command:
prlimit --pid $$ --core



h. Debugging Tips:

If the issue persists, enable debugging for PAM modules by adding debug to the pam_limits.so line in /etc/pam.d/common-session and check logs in /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/secure for detailed error messages.

i. Update and Reinstall PAM Packages:
- Ensuring that your PAM packages are up to date. Sometimes, bugs or outdated packages can cause unexpected behavior. You can update PAM packages using your package manager.
j. Checking for Conflicting Settings:

Ensure no conflicting settings in other configuration files, such as /etc/profile, ~/.bashrc, or /etc/bash.bashrc. These files might have ulimit -c settings that override your PAM configurations but in my opinion this is just like as a thing to check off as it is unlikely to happen.

